# Using license_specifications into terraform EKS self_managed_node_group module

Tags: terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to define license_specifications within my Terraform configuration.
The error message I'm getting is as follows:

```
│ Error: Reference to undeclared resource
│ 
│   on .terraform/modules/self_managed_node_group/modules/self-managed-node-group/main.tf line 288, in resource "aws_launch_template" "this":
│  288:       license_configuration_arn = license_specifications.value.license_configuration_arn
│ 
│ A managed resource "license_specifications" "value" has not been declared in module.self_managed_node_group.
```

I would greatly appreciate any assistance in resolving this issue. Thank you!

My configuration

```
module "self_managed_node_group" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws//modules/self-managed-node-group"
  version = "19.16.0"

  name                = local.eks_name
  cluster_name        = module.eks.cluster_name
  cluster_version     = var.eks_version
  cluster_endpoint    = module.eks.cluster_endpoint
  cluster_auth_base64 = module.eks.cluster_certificate_authority_data

  ....

  placement = {
    tenancy                 = "host"
    host_resource_group_arn = "X"
  }

  license_specifications = {
    license_configuration_arn = "arn:aws:license-manager:us-east-1:XXXXXX:license-configuration:XXXXXXXXX"
  }
}
```

Here, dynamic block from module

```
  dynamic "license_specification" {
    for_each = length(var.license_specifications) > 0 ? var.license_specifications : {}

    content {
      license_configuration_arn = license_specifications.value.license_configuration_arn
    }
  }
```